# runserver command doesn't do anything

Tags: python, django

I activate the venv and when I try to run the `python manage.py runserver` command on VScode PowerShell it doesn't do anything, no errors, nothing, I enter the localhost to see if the server was activated with no notice but it doesn't appear. Note that the project was first made by a friend that uses Linux and I imported the project using GitHub on Windows, I'm thinking that there may be problems because of that?

I tried running it on cmd and I couldn't run the activate command this time, apparently I need to use a power shell to run Linux like commands?

Comment: Try creating your own virtualenv and then install all the packages from requirements.txt. You can use this command to activate the virtual env on your windows machine: venv\Scripts\activate while being in the same directory where there is venv folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open PowerShell terminal in VSCode and change the directory to folder where your manage.py file resides.
Create a virtual environment and activate it.
Install all the dependancies using following command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now run the server.

Comment: I created a new venv and activated it, but when I try to run the pip install -r requirements.txt this error appears ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt , I tried to find the file but there is only a requirements.py not .txt